# Tracking and hiding old element after cloning in jquery

Tags: jquery, clone

I am trying to clone and element and then hide the old element. Actually I want to use the event bindings of the old element but to have the old element moved to a new location in the DOM.

I clone it and append it where needed.

Now, when I try to hide the old element the clone copy itself gets hidden and old element is not affected.

### Please help. :)

```
var $thead = $("#UserDataTable thead");
var $tfoot = $("#UserDataTable tfoot#myfooter");
var $clone = $tfoot.clone(true, true).attr("id", "ClonedFoot");
$thead.after($clone);
$("#UserDataTable tfoot#myfooter").hide();
```

---

the last line of code hides the cloned element itself. I think it should hide the original element with id myfooter.

Answer (score 2):

Issue exists because in your code you hide by traversing the DOM again. You already bind each element in vars, just use them again:

```
var $thead = $("#UserDataTable thead");
var $tfoot = $("#UserDataTable tfoot#myfooter");
var $clone = $tfoot.clone().attr("id", "ClonedFoot");
// now hide the original
$tfoot.hide();
$thead.after($clone);
```

Comment: Thanks. But this code behaves the same way as my code. I am using IE8 and jquery-1.8.2, btw.